# Conditional Formatting: Highlight every other row in excel if row not blank?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am using the following conditional format to highlight every other row in a worksheet:

```
=MOD(ROW(),2)=1
```

This also highlights blank rows. I do not want it to. Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: Add another rule for the blanks and set the format as default then order this before the rule you've shown above, also select the option "Stop if true" for the blank rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are done already with half of the part. Please add this single conditional formatting formula to complete your task,

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=1,IF((1:1=""),FALSE,TRUE))
```

This formula just validates the presence of blank in every row that you selected. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this format to column `A2:A1000`.

```
=IF($A2<>"",MOD(ROW(),2)=1)
```

If the cell is not blank then the format will occur.